# How to manage component status with observables in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, observable, delay, ng-class

### Context

In an Angular project, I have made a component to encapsulate the logic of a submit request page (code below).

This page has two subcomponents that define specific forms (**firstForm** and **secondForm**) and a submit button.

Each subcomponent has an input for the **disabled** state

```js
@Input() set disabled(value: boolean | null) {
    if (value === null) {
      value = false;
    }
    this._disabled = value;
    this._onDisabledChange();
  }
```

and an output to emit if the form is **valid** or not:

```js
@Output() onValidChange: EventEmitter<boolean> = new EventEmitter();
```

I want that to enable the following form, the previous ones have to be valid.
These would be the enabled dependencies:

- first-form *-(depends-on)->* no one
- second-form *-(depends-on)->* first-form
- submit button -(depends-on)-> first-form & second-form

### Problem

When first-form and second-form are completed (submit enabled), and I delete one of first-form's required input (so first-form is invalid), this happens:

- second-form updates to disabled (correct)
- submit doesn't update to disabled style until I click outside the input (incorrect)

I would like that submit disabled style updated instantly.

#### Note:

I am using `changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush`. As a test I used `Default` strategy, and the console showed the error `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError`.

### Code

As this is a complex problem, I have simplified the code, leaving only the relevant parts.

Components have another EventEmitter to emit the form values, but here I want to focus on the valid state.

#### Html template

```html
<div>
  <first-form (onValidChange)="firstFormValid = $event"></first-form>

  <second-form
    [disabled]="!(isSecondStepEnabled$ | async)"
    (onValidChange)="secondFormValid = $event"
  ></second-form>

  <div [ngClass]="{ disabled: !(isSubmitStepEnabled$ | async) }">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <button
          id="submit"
          [disabled]="!(isSubmitStepEnabled$ | async)"
          (click)="submit()"
        >
          Submit
        </button>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

#### Angular Component

```js
export class PageComponent {

  private _isFirstFormValid$: BehaviorSubject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject<
    boolean
  >(false);

  private _isSecondFormValid$: BehaviorSubject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject<
    boolean
  >(false);

  set firstFormValid(valid: boolean) {
    this._isFirstFormValid$.next(valid);
  }

  set secondFormValid(valid: boolean) {
    this._isSecondFormValid$.next(valid);
  }

  get isSecondFormValid$(): Observable<boolean> {
    return this._isSecondFormValid$.asObservable();
  }

  isFirstStepCompleted$: Observable<
    boolean
  > = this._isFirstFormValid$.asObservable();

  isSecondStepEnabled$: Observable<
    boolean
  > = this._isFirstFormValid$.asObservable();

  isSecondStepCompleted$: Observable<boolean> = combineLatest([
    this.isSecondStepEnabled$,
    this.isSecondFormValid$
  ]).pipe(map(this._areAllTrue()));

  isSubmitStepEnabled$: Observable<boolean> = combineLatest([
    this.isFirstStepCompleted$,
    this.isSecondStepCompleted$
  ]).pipe(map(this._areAllTrue()));

  private _areAllTrue(): (value: boolean[]) => boolean {
    return (values: boolean[]) => {
      return values.every(valid => valid === true);
    };
  }

  submit() {
      // call external service
  }
}
```

---

#### Version

```
Angular CLI: 9.0.4
Node: 13.6.0
OS: darwin x64
Angular: 9.0.4
rxjs: 6.5.4
typescript: 3.7.5
webpack: 4.41.6
```

---

### Solution

The only solution I found was using `delay(0)` on the Observable `isSubmitStepEnabled$`.

```js
  isSubmitStepEnabled$: Observable<boolean> = combineLatest([
    this.isFirstStepCompleted$,
    this.isSecondStepCompleted$
  ]).pipe(delay(0), map(this._areAllTrue()));
```

I think it is not a good solution and maybe I have a structure problem.

Thanks everyone!

Comment: Hi @adrisons, I'm wondering why have you wrapped every single value with Observables? Everything happen within one component and his children so I don't think it is necessary, but it make code much complex and unreadable

Comment: Child components (first-form and second-form) can change their output, so I want to keep listening to that changes so in my parent component I can disable some elements

Comment: But Change Detection is for that. You can have setters in parent component and update some properties. When those properties changed (so children inputs changed) Change Detection will know about it and rerender those components

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the solution I have found (without using `delay` function):

Simply replace `asObservable` (when I want to get the stream from the behaviourSubject) with `.pipe(shareReplay({ refCount: true, bufferSize: ONCE }))`.

The difference between these two are:

- with `asObservable` a new subscription is being created each time it is invoked (by a "listener").
- with [`shareReplay`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/multicasting/sharereplay), it's like you have one subscription and its data is broadcasted to all your "listeners"

With `asObservable`, my code didn't run change detection until I clicked outside the input.